# Should the downvoters/upvoters have enough reputations on all the tags of the question/answers?

Tags: feature-request, tags, reputation, down-votes

It is observed that the stackexcange permits to downvote/upvote by just having minimum cumulative reputation of all tags even though the member doesn't possess enough reputations in them.

"Subject matter" should be given appropriate higher weightage over clarity, spelling, readability, etc!

I propose, subject to the approval of board of stackexchange, only members whoever possesses minimum appropriate reputations in all tags of the question/answer to permit to upvote/downvote.

Comment: What about upvotes?

Comment: _"2 members downvoted though they don't have enough knowledge in the area"_ How did you come to know who DVed and what their experience really is?

Comment: They never asked any question or answered to any question related to asn.1

Comment: How do you know who DVed at all?? Also that they never asked a question or answered for a particular niche tag , doesn't necessarily mean _"lack of experience"_.

Comment: Hi upvoters/downvoters, please evaluate and give its merits and demerits for upvoting/downvoting for better understanding!

Comment: Are you familiar with DVs at meta [tag:feature-request]s?

Comment: Here on Meta, people often vote on feature requests based on whether they agree or disagree with the proposed feature.

Comment: My tag score for the tags on this question  is 555+75+143+49. Is that enough to vote on this question and all its answers?

Comment: If this were implemented, then *nobody* could vote on new tags at all; nobody would have the required rep to do so, as it's brand new.  And it can be abused, too, by just including an obscure tag in your question, and voila!  Immune to judgement.  In essence, an incredibly bad idea.

Comment: You don't necessarily need domain knowledge to know if a question is bad/should be downvoted. If a question is simply "gimme da codez", it doesn't matter what the question is about. Anyone with minimal experience on the site should be able to recognize that that's offtopic and be able to vote accordingly.

Answer (score 13):

If this were implemented I think it would undermine the purpose of downvoting which is to maintain question quality.

Question quality is as much about criteria such as clarity, spelling, readability, etc as it is about technical knowledge of the post's subject matter.

Those with high reputation in a tag may write posts that others have improved to get them those votes.

Those with no reputation in a tag may be able to improve a tag's grammar and readability dramatically (and help it get upvotes).

If we trust those users to improve posts then I think we should also trust them to recognize when posts need to be improved, and that is what downvotes indicate.

Answer (score 8):

Some questions are just **off-topic**, regardless of the tags or not, and those deserve to be downvoted by anyone.

Some answers are also **not an answer**, regardless of the tags or not, and those deserve to be downvoted by anyone.

There are possibly *many other cases* where this feature request would prohibit quality control on Stack Exchange, regardless of the technical knowledge.

Answer (score 7):

Well, when you get enough reputation and get engaged enough in a site - you're probably not going to want to downvote things for fun. I often find the same folks hanging around tags they care about, even on smaller sites. Downvoting is actually an essential part of content curation on regular sites, and people shouldn't take it lightly.

I think we make a few assumptions in the question that are incorrect. Voting is *anonymous* and there's no way to figure out who voted on a specific question

As for answers - I don't always answer stuff on *everything* I know about, and on many sites, tag badges are difficult to get. You're essentially expecting users to get a minimum of 100 rep spread over many answers, for something that is semi trivial to get now by design *on each tag there is*.

> minimum appropriate reputations in all tags of the question/answer

Just makes downvoting impossible, and encourages the use of tags tactically. It kind of just isn't going to work at all, unless your goal was zero downvotes. Oh and stealing from the comments - (sorry @fbueckert) - no one could ever downvote a question with a newish tag until someone got an appropriate badge on it.

> "Subject matter" should be given appropriate higher weightage over clarity, spelling, readability, etc!

To an extent, quality issues are fixable. Unless of course, its hard to tell what the post is about. In a sense, we expect a minimum effort for comprehensibility and that gives people a better chance to understand if your post reflects your knowledge of the subject matter.